# Calculate UIButton Pressed Duration

Tags: cocoa-touch, uibutton

Based on duration of UIButton Pressed, the same Buttton  has to perform different tasks.

How to calculate duration of UIButton pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Us can set 2 actions to your button and measure the time that passes between these 2 methods are called:

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 20.0);
[btn setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(userEndsTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(userStartsTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

and in the two methods that get called you can do your duration measurement:

```
- (void)userEndsTap:(id)sender {
   NSLog(@"user ends tap");
   // stop measurement an do something different for different durations
}

- (void)userStartsTap:(id)sender {
   NSLog(@"user starts tap");
   // start measurement
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Attach a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to your button and set the `minimumPressDuration` property.
You can attach multiple gesture recognizers to the same button for different minimal press duration.

If you have "conflicts" between different gesture recognizers, you can settle them with `–requireGestureRecognizerToFail:` to specify that a gesture will only be recognized if another one is not.

Have a look at the [relevant document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIGestureRecognizer).